# prooftrees (tikz) style arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees, forest

Ive been trying to create decent-looking prooftrees using the forest package within the prooftrees package. Im relatively new to Tex in general and Im trying to create a ./style for my prooftrees that includes an argument so I can get some text when it branches out. Currently I have this

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  smullyan tableaux/.style={
    for tree={
      math content
    },
    where n children=1{
      !1.before computing xy={l=\baselineskip},
      !1.no edge
    }{},
    closed/.style={
      label=below:$\times$
    },
    open/.style={
      label=below:$\bigcirc$
    },
    text/.style={
      label=below:{#1}
    }
  },
}
\begin{document}
% and where I'm trying to call "text" with the argument #1
\begin{forest}
  smullyan tableaux
  [\forall{x}(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \wedge \forall{x}P(x) \rightarrow \forall{x}Q(x): F
    [\mid
      [\forall{x}(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \wedge \forall{x}P(x): T
        [\forall{x}Q(x): F
          [\mid
            [Q(t): F
              [\mid
                [\forall{x}(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)): T
                  [\forall{x}P(x): T
                    [\mid
                      [P(t) \rightarrow Q(t): T, text={Hey}
                        [P(t): F
                          [\mid
                            [P(t): T, closed
                            ]
                          ]
                        ]
                        [Q(t): T, closed
                        ]
                      ]
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always post complete examples we can compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to double `#`, i.e., `text/.style={label=below:{##1}}`. The reason is that this definition appears itself in a definiton; with each nesting level you have to double the `#` symbols. If you would define `text` not as part of `smullyan tableaux` but outside of it, your definition with one `#` would work.

Note that there is a package [prooftrees](http://ctan.org/pkg/prooftrees); if you do more proofs, have a look at it, maybe it is useful.

Here is a reduced version of your proof tree, as a proof that your definition now works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  smullyan tableaux/.style={
    for tree={
      math content
    },
    where n children=1{
      !1.before computing xy={l=\baselineskip},
      !1.no edge
    }{},
    closed/.style={
      label=below:$\times$
    },
    open/.style={
      label=below:$\bigcirc$
    },
    text/.style={
      label=below:{##1}
    }
  },
}
\begin{forest}
  smullyan tableaux
  [P(t) \rightarrow Q(t): T, text={Hey}
    [P(t): F
      [\mid
        [P(t): T, closed
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [Q(t): T, closed
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing the assignment by creating a new style for each double-branch.... Sad to hear that all I was missing was an extra # however Ill keep it in mind for next time. Also yea I was trying to work with the "big" prooftree package but couldnt get it to work so I just ended up with the forest one and tried my best from there. I thought the outcome was respectable anyway.

Comment: @RasmusMichelsen If you post your attempt with `prooftrees`, I might be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `prooftrees` version of `smullyan tableaux`. Note that I have change the `text` style to `my text` to avoid overwriting the standard Ti*k*Z key.

If we use `prooftrees`, we can simplify the tree specification significantly by eliminating all the `\mid`s and letting `prooftrees` draw the branches. This requires `single branches`, which is not default. The only downside is that we need to then use `grouped` when a wff is not the first formula resulting from an inference, since `prooftrees` obviously can't tell the difference between this and the case in which it is the second and no branch is required. But this just requires adding `grouped` for wffs which should be grouped with their predecessors.

To eliminate the numbering, we use `not line numbering`. To customise the closure symbol, we use `close with`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\forestset{
  smullyan tableaux/.style={
    close with=\ensuremath{\times},
    my text/.style={% don't overwrite a standard TikZ key!
      label={[yshift=-5pt]below:{##1}},
      l sep'+=5pt,
    },
    not line numbering,
    single branches
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
  {
    smullyan tableaux
  }
  [\forall{x}(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \land \forall{x}P(x) \rightarrow \forall{x}Q(x): F
    [\forall{x}(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \land \forall{x}P(x): T
      [\forall{x}Q(x): F, grouped
        [Q(t): F
          [\forall{x}(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)): T
            [\forall{x}P(x): T, grouped
              [P(t) \rightarrow Q(t): T, my text={Hey}
                [P(t): F
                  [P(t): T, close
                  ]
                ]
                [Q(t): T, close
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image: smullyan tableaux prooftrees prooftree]

Comment: Yes thank you so much, I dont have the time to go through and try and do it with the real prooftree package atm but I got it to work in a kind of hacky way I suppose. Thanks so much for your work (I found the forestset styles in one of your threads I believe). Much appreciate the work.